# Why kotlin wrong: val minT: Long = -9223372036854775808L //Long.MIN_VALUE

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Kotlin's Long.MIN_VALUE == -9223372036854775808, but when I write:

`val minT: Long = -9223372036854775808L //Long.MIN_VALUE`

IDEA say it was wrong.

Dmitry Jemerov told me this because the `-` sign in Kotlin is not part of the constant but rather the unary minus operator applied to the constant value, and 9223372036854775808L is one larger than the maximum possible positive value for the Long type.

But now, why Int is right :

`val minI: Int = -2147483648 //Int.MIN_VALUE`

Look here:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand your question - did you expect `val minI: Int = -2147483648` to raise an error, as well?

Comment: Note: in kotlin-stdlib, this constant is defined as `public const val MIN_VALUE: Long = -9223372036854775807L - 1L` (you can navigate to declaration of `Long.MIN_VALUE`).

Comment: Yeah.I expect `val minI: Int = -2147483648` to raise an error.Thank you for  your answer,I had read the Long's constant ,and it's exactly what you said. Now, I know `val val minT: Long = (-9223372036854775807L - 1L)` is work, but it looks so strange.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they bound like that value may need to fall within -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775808 because of Long.